# How to calculate DataGrid Cell Value based on other Cells Value?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid B_DG that is bound to a List..

I Want the cell "Total" value to be calculated based on the values of other three cells "Price", "Quan", and "Discount".

Comment: You may want to read up on databinding because you can put that very function right into the model that is being displayed, create a property next to Price, Quan and Discount and name it Total then calculate it in the model's getter method.  Finally use that model for your binding and you're done!

Comment: Does this Work If these cells are editable?

I want Total Cell to vary based on the input value of the other cells

Comment: Yes in binding this is called two-way binding.